# Ubuntu 16.04 switching workspace left to right does not work

Tags: 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 on my laptop and enabled workspaces.
Then I configure it out, that switching from **left to right** does not work but from **top to bottom** works fine.

Is it an operating bug?

**Update**
[image]

Comment: and? It shows me terminal

Comment: Sorry wrong question

Comment: Did you try switching with the workspaces icon or using Expo plugin with SUPER + A ? To make sure workspaces is working

Comment: I have four workspaces and move top to bottom or reverse it works but not left to right or reverse.

Comment: Expo plugin works fine.

Comment: Well, that means your workspace is configured as a column. You can change this with **compizconfig-settings-manager**

Comment: I change it as a column and it still does not work.

Comment: Before we go on, log out and in your session. then another try. Just you know the name of this plugin is Viewport Switcher, it is in the Desktop section of CompizConfig Settings Manager. Maybe you would like to check on the setting and even post a screenshot of that too (after you log back in your session)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67124/discussion-between-userdepth-and-zero-coding).

Answer (score 0):

Install CompizConfig Setting manager

```
apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Go into General Options and into the Desktop Size tab. There you can set the horizontal and vertical size.

[image]

Comment: it does not work. I can not switch from left to right.

Comment: Post a screenshot of Expo

Comment: I did it. Please take a look.